# Configuring fresh copy of apache on RHEL?

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration

I need to setup a copy of Apache and I'm wondering if there is a good (and updated) walk-through that I can use?

Answer (score 4):

`yum install httpd` installs Apache. It brings a sane default configuration, so other than dropping documents in the documents folder, if you don't have a special need, you are done.

If you do have special needs, we need to know them in order to help.

Answer (score 1):

Red Hat themselves actually provide their own tutorials on configuring and setting up Apache; if you want it straight from the source,

- [Apache HTTPD Server Configuration](https://www.redhat.com/docs/manuals/enterprise/RHEL-3-Manual/sysadmin-guide/ch-httpdconfig.html)
- [Apache HTTPD Secure Server Configuration](http://www.redhat.com/docs/manuals/enterprise/RHEL-4-Manual/sysadmin-guide/ch-httpd-secure-server.html)

Answer (score 0):

[HOW-TO Forge](http://howtoforge.com/) has some very good step by step guides on how to setup not only Apache but a wide range of applications for linux. Choose CentOS as its redhat based and tweak it abit for the repository